# Fixed Header - opens and push content

Tags: jquery, html, css, header, fixed

I have get a fixed div that contain some data the the user can choose from, and just below it i got many products according to the user selections.

```
.header{
position:fixed;
}
```

the fixed div is 10px height, but when the user want to change selection it grows and reveal more data -with Jquery slideToggle.

the problem is when it opens it covers some of the products.
is there any solution for it so when it toggling the products section will pushed down?

example - https://jsfiddle.net/pv41257p/10/

Comment: does your problem reflecting in above link?

Comment: Even though you do such, when you scroll, the header would be fixed so it will come over content when it is slide down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a solution for you.

**jQuery**

```
$('.header_title').click(function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.header_data').slideToggle();    
    $('.header').css( "position","relative" );
});

$(document).click(function(){
     $('.header_data').slideUp();
    $('.header').css( "position","fixed" );
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/pv41257p/16/)

Comment: Kindly check out what actually OP wants. This is not even little close to what OP wants.

Comment: You are still misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can **push down content only when you are at top of page**. But when you scroll down the content would not be direct after header so, it is **not possible to push down any content(content below header) at anytime(any scroll position)**.

Still i have something better that suits in your situation.

When you scroll and you are out of `.header` div height the JQuery would give `position:fixed` to `.header` div. But if you are at start of page you can slide with below content pushed downward.

[JSFiddle : Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pv41257p/13/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".header_title").click(function () {
        $(".header_data").slideToggle();
    });
    $(window).scroll(function()
 {
        var h = $(".header").outerHeight();
        var curScroll = $(this).scrollTop(); 
        if(curScroll > h)
        {
         $(".header").css("position","fixed");
        }
        else
        {
           $(".header").css("position","relative");       
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.header {
    display:block;
    width:70%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:999;
}
.header_title {
    
    color:white;
    height:10px;
}
.header_data {
    display:none;
}
.header_data span {
    display:block;
}
.products {
    position:relative;
    /*padding-top:18px;*/
    background-color:green;
}
.pro {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"> 
    <span class="header_title">HEADER TITLE - click for more data</span>

    <div class="header_data"> 
        <span>cheap</span>
        <span>cool</span>
        <span>gadget</span>
        <span>small</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="products">
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
    <div class="pro">this is a product!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the hidden block (the collapsing content) out of the header. Place it directly after the header with `display:none;` and then toggle it's view with jquery. This will keep the header fixed, but allow the pages content to be pushed down when the collapsable content expands.

Also, add a margin-top:10px; to the collapsing content, so when it expands, it's below the fixed header. This will require scrolling back to the top of the page though when you've scrolled down and then activate the collapsing content.